# Ubuntu 19.10 slow boot, despite systemd-analyze critical-chain claiming ~11 seconds

Tags: boot, 19.10

Machine in question is an Acer Aspire 5 A15-52G-53PU with the following specs:

- CPU: i5-8265 1.6-3.9GHz
- 8GB RAM
- SSD (two partitions, 537MB EFI, 256GB Ext4)

Measured with a stopwatch, it takes about **1min10s** to show the desktop after pressing the power button and another 40 seconds after that to open a web browser, which seems really strange because I've got another ancient 8 year old laptop that can boot Windows 10 in like 15 seconds.

I've got a 2 GB swap file, according to `sudo swapon --show`.

Another problem I have with this machine is that when it wakes up after sleeping it's briefly usable (usually just enough to type in my password and confirm), then freezes for several seconds before becoming responsive again.

Here's some `systemd-analyze` output:

```
$ systemd-analyze
Startup finished in 1.529s (kernel) + 11.126s (userspace) = 12.655s 
graphical.target reached after 11.115s in userspace
```

`critical-chain`

```
$ systemd-analyze critical-chain
The time when unit became active or started is printed after the "@" character.
The time the unit took to start is printed after the "+" character.

graphical.target @11.115s
└─multi-user.target @11.115s
  └─snapd.seeded.service @10.350s +764ms
    └─snapd.service @5.098s +5.247s
      └─basic.target @4.884s
        └─sockets.target @4.883s
          └─snapd.socket @4.864s +18ms
            └─sysinit.target @4.844s
              └─systemd-timesyncd.service @4.473s +370ms
                └─systemd-tmpfiles-setup.service @4.218s +248ms
                  └─local-fs.target @4.214s
                    └─run-user-1000.mount @9.998s
                      └─swap.target @571ms
                        └─swapfile.swap @406ms +150ms
                          └─systemd-remount-fs.service @335ms +45ms
                            └─systemd-journald.socket @320ms
                              └─-.mount @300ms
                                └─system.slice @300ms
                                  └─-.slice @300ms
```

`blame`

```
$ systemd-analyze blame
          9.105s fwupd.service
          6.453s upower.service
          5.247s snapd.service
          4.465s networkd-dispatcher.service
          4.040s udisks2.service
          3.720s ModemManager.service
          3.574s snap-gnome\x2dsystem\x2dmonitor-107.mount
          3.558s libvirtd.service
          3.515s snap-blender-33.mount
          3.507s snap-gnome\x2dsystem\x2dmonitor-111.mount
          3.454s snap-gnome\x2dlogs-73.mount
          3.384s snap-keepassxc-625.mount
          3.373s dev-sda2.device
          3.358s snap-gnome\x2dcalculator-536.mount
          3.345s snap-blender-34.mount
          3.324s snap-core-8039.mount
          3.290s snap-postman-94.mount
          3.289s snap-firefox-280.mount
          3.280s snap-gnome\x2d3\x2d28\x2d1804-110.mount
          3.265s snap-core18-1223.mount
          3.246s snap-postman-96.mount
          3.141s accounts-daemon.service
          2.995s dev-loop8.device
          2.965s dev-loop9.device
          2.905s dev-loop11.device
          2.774s dev-loop12.device
          2.703s dev-loop14.device
          2.636s dev-loop16.device
          2.548s dev-loop19.device
          2.547s dev-loop15.device
          2.507s dev-loop18.device
          2.492s dev-loop21.device
          2.477s dev-loop20.device
          2.391s dev-loop22.device
          2.335s systemd-resolved.service
          2.333s dev-loop30.device
          2.319s dev-loop23.device
          2.236s dev-loop26.device
          2.160s dev-loop29.device
          2.158s dev-loop28.device
          2.114s dev-loop25.device
          1.937s avahi-daemon.service
          1.925s bluetooth.service
          1.925s systemd-logind.service
          1.924s thermald.service
          1.903s grub-initrd-fallback.service
          1.889s secureboot-db.service
          1.873s switcheroo-control.service
          1.871s rsyslog.service
          1.869s lm-sensors.service
          1.859s wpa_supplicant.service
          1.838s apport.service
          1.836s grub-common.service
          1.825s gpu-manager.service
          1.792s NetworkManager.service
          1.726s vpnagentd.service
          1.148s snap-android\x2dstudio-80.mount
          1.087s snap-gnome\x2dcharacters-359.mount
           940ms snap-gnome\x2d3\x2d26\x2d1604-98.mount
           938ms snap-gnome\x2dlogs-81.mount
           891ms colord.service
           883ms snap-pycharm\x2dprofessional-171.mount
           879ms snap-gtk2\x2dcommon\x2dthemes-5.mount
           829ms snap-gnome\x2d3\x2d28\x2d1804-91.mount
           821ms snap-code-20.mount
           818ms snap-discord-93.mount
           775ms snap-gtk\x2dcommon\x2dthemes-1353.mount
           774ms snap-gimp-227.mount
           764ms snapd.seeded.service
           749ms snap-eclipse-40.mount
           707ms snap-keepassxc-590.mount
           701ms dev-loop10.device
           672ms user@1000.service
           645ms gdm.service
           573ms snap-core-7917.mount
           545ms snap-gnome\x2dcalculator-544.mount
           534ms ssh.service
           526ms snap-gnome\x2dcharacters-367.mount
           521ms dev-loop0.device
           512ms apparmor.service
           504ms dev-loop1.device
           460ms systemd-journald.service
           446ms dev-loop2.device
           425ms dev-loop17.device
           422ms dev-loop13.device
           386ms snap-core18-1265.mount
           386ms systemd-rfkill.service
           385ms snap-intellij\x2didea\x2dultimate-188.mount
           380ms systemd-fsck@dev-disk-by\x2duuid-BEB4\x2dA3A8.service
           379ms snap-intellij\x2didea\x2dultimate-181.mount
           376ms snap-gimp-189.mount
           373ms snap-discord-101.mount
           373ms snap-gtk\x2dcommon\x2dthemes-1313.mount
           370ms systemd-timesyncd.service
           352ms dev-loop34.device
           325ms dev-loop35.device
           321ms dev-loop3.device
           308ms dev-loop33.device
           295ms dev-loop4.device
           280ms dev-loop7.device
           280ms dev-loop37.device
           274ms snap-android\x2dstudio-81.mount
           265ms ebtables.service
           252ms dev-loop32.device
           248ms systemd-tmpfiles-setup.service
           231ms snap-gnome\x2d3\x2d26\x2d1604-97.mount
           229ms dev-loop6.device
           211ms pppd-dns.service
           211ms dev-loop31.device
           206ms snap-code-21.mount
           201ms polkit.service
           192ms dev-loop24.device
           166ms hddtemp.service
           159ms systemd-journal-flush.service
           159ms dev-loop38.device
           157ms dev-loop39.device
           150ms swapfile.swap
           131ms kerneloops.service
           129ms packagekit.service
           120ms systemd-user-sessions.service
           108ms systemd-udevd.service
           105ms qemu-kvm.service
           103ms openvpn.service
            99ms systemd-udev-trigger.service
            96ms plymouth-read-write.service
            94ms keyboard-setup.service
            86ms setvtrgb.service
            84ms systemd-backlight@backlight:intel_backlight.service
            79ms boot-efi.mount
            74ms bolt.service
            72ms networking.service
            70ms dev-loop36.device
            67ms lvm2-monitor.service
            58ms libvirt-guests.service
            54ms console-setup.service
            49ms snap-pycharm\x2dprofessional-173.mount
            49ms snap-firefox-287.mount
            45ms ufw.service
            45ms systemd-remount-fs.service
            45ms dev-mqueue.mount
            44ms blk-availability.service
            40ms sys-kernel-debug.mount
            38ms dev-hugepages.mount
            38ms rtkit-daemon.service
            33ms user-runtime-dir@1000.service
            32ms systemd-update-utmp.service
            31ms systemd-modules-load.service
            31ms kmod-static-nodes.service
            25ms systemd-sysctl.service
            21ms sys-kernel-config.mount
            20ms systemd-sysusers.service
            20ms systemd-random-seed.service
            19ms sys-fs-fuse-connections.mount
            18ms snapd.socket
            18ms dev-loop40.device
            13ms dev-loop5.device
            13ms plymouth-quit-wait.service
            13ms systemd-tmpfiles-setup-dev.service
             7ms systemd-update-utmp-runlevel.service
             3ms ifupdown-pre.service
```